# How to save and load ordered data using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have an application that works off different jobs. Jobs are described by an interface, like this:

```
public interface Job {

    void start();

    String getName();

    void setName(String name);

    // Getters and setters for other properties

}
```

The jobs are persisted in a database. Now there is the requirement that some groups of jobs have to be executed in order.
When I create the jobs in the program, there is no problem, because the jobs are put in a queue.
But when I recreate persisted jobs I have no information about the original order.

I thought about adding another member called `preceder` that stores the preceding job. This would give me something like a linked list and I could alter the table like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+
| id | preceder_id | name  | others... |
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+
|  1 | null        | Job 1 | ...       |
|  2 | 1           | Job 2 | ...       |
|  3 | 2           | Job 3 | ...       |
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+
```

But how can I use Spring Data JPA and a `JPARepository` to get an ordered list of such a group?

Comment: hmm cant you just use "OrderBy" method name support?

Comment: Yes, I think that would work, but first I would have to get the whole group. Or could I just do it the other way and say that each job can have a following job and would Spring/Hibernate then automatically load the next job? How do I have to annotate this?

Comment: In my view it would be better if you make data in your table to be ordered. In this way whenever you will fetch the data, you will get them ordered as per your ordering.

Comment: The ordering is not my real problem. My problem is that I don't know how to receive the group of jobs that belong together. For example: I know only about job 1. Thus I select the job where id equals 1. Now all following jobs should be loaded, too. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map this using a self-join:

```
@Table(name = "JOB")
public class Job implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) //or some other strategy
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "preceder_id")
    private Job previousJob;
}
```

Assuming you can load the last job in the chain you should then be able to do some kind of recursive call up the chain.

```
Job job = loadJobFromDB();
runJob(job);

public void runJob(Job Job){
    if(job.getPreviousJob() != null){
        runJob(job.getPreviousJob());
    }

    job.start();
}
```

The other options would be to change your schema to add a job group and a job sequence for each job within the group.